# same user with administrative rights on all the servers in single domain versus domainadmin as a part of administrator group in all the servers

Tags: administrator, windows-domain, windows-server-2003

Same user with administrative rights on all the servers in single domain vomain user as a part of administrator group in all the servers:

Same user is configured as administrator on all the servers in one domain at windows 2003 server.

Should this user be made part of domain admin and then this can be set up in the group of administrator for all the servers. How this is technically different?

Answer (score 1):

Domain administrators are automatically granted Administrator access to all machines in the domain, without having to manage it at each server.

Domain Administrators have local-admin equivalent access on each machine, but local Administrators don't have admin access to domain-level administrator resources.

That's the main point and the difference -- centralized management of the domain credentials vs. individual credentials management at each server, and access scope.

Say you wanted to change the admin's password and you had 100 servers, would you rather update a single user's credentials in one place, or visit 100 servers to update the credentials, one at a time?

As well, Domain-level credentials get passed around securely from domain resource to domain resource as you access them, avoiding the need to log in to and/or store credentials for each device.

Say you created a new intranet site or web app for the admin, which requires Windows-level authentication. Would you rather add and maintain a single domain user's credential to the allow list, or add one for each possible machine-level administrator account?